# Trigger an action when user open the location settings in android

Tags: android

Here is the scenario, I am forcing the user to enable location if user turned off the location, I start a periodic service  with job scheduler, which will continuously check if location is enabled,  if location is not enabled the I show a dialog to enable location. I  turned of the job service when user enable the location.

The problem is when user open the location settings from the dialog the periodic job service still show the dialog to go to settings page to turn the location. I don't want to show the dialog to user when user already opened settings page.

Is there any intent which will be fired when user open the location settings ?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop a service when setting is open and again start a service when back to application by using activityForResult()